# Can we allow longer tags?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that it's common (makes sense to me) to put package names in as tags here, but not all will fit. For example, I couldn't fit "pointcloud_to_laserscan" in my latest question because they're limited to 20 and it's 23.

If not, well, no big deal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9451/can-we-allow-longer-tags?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've bumped it up to 40.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0